# How to analzye csv data on R using QCApro package

Tags: r, database, typescript, csv, analysis

I want to analyze data using a fuzzy set QCA (Qualitative Comparative Analysis)method. I am using the R package QCApro to do the task. It is my first time trying it on R, could you assist me, please.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Your question is too general. When you have tried something and get stuck, please ask a more specific question.

Comment: A good starting point with any new package is to find the reference manual on CRAN (for QCA pro, look here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/QCApro/index.html). I'd also look at the 'QCA' package, which is excellent (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/QCA/QCA.pdf)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm looking at the manual now.